# Ext.util.KeyMap destroy method

Tags: extjs, destroy

```
init: function(){
    this.callParent(arguments);
    map = new Ext.util.KeyMap(Ext.getBody(),{                
    key: Ext.EventObject.F8,
    scope: this,
    target:this,
    fn: this.onKeyPress
    });
}
```

In the init method takes subscription  on event. Is there a method, when I leave the page to perform map.destroy?The problem is when I go to a page occurs subscription event and pressing the F8 works everywhere. How to make that worked only on this page?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens because you are targeting `Ext.getBody()` with your KeyMap.
Even though `target` points to `this`, you are adding it `Ext.getBody()` before, that means that no matter where you are on the page, the KeyMap will work.
So you have two options:
1) Assign your component element to your target. Note that the method `onKeyPress` will only be called if there is something selected in your component element.

Example: 
If you set target: component.getEl(), the `onKeyPress` method will only be called if you press F8 while a textfield is focused inside your panel.

2) Keep adding it to `Ext.getBody()` if you want the `onKeyPress` method to be called no matter if there is anything focused on the page. But if it has to work only when a specific page is active, you should add conditionals to your `onKeyPress` method.

Example:

```
onKeyPress : function() {
    currentTab = this.getActiveTab();
    if (currentTab.title=='Foo') {
        console.log('You hit F8');
    }
}
```

Here is fiddle demonstrating the process: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g7a

Comment: Method getActiveTab() is not available.Dont know why. I need use F8 only target this page to show some dialog.

Comment: getActiveTab is only present in the TabPanel Class, you need to adapt the example to your needs.